After giving permission 550 to usr/share folder in Ubuntu and after restarting getting error while start system
By mistake I have given permission 550 to folder usr/share in Ubuntu while installing apache2. However after giving permission, some unusual things happened so I restarted my system and got the below error, Now I can't start my system.
Is there any way to give original/default permission to folder usr/share, so might be working or Is there any other way to get out of this without reinstalling Ubuntu?
Error image:

Or any option using the below screen where I can run the command.


There is no folder /usr/shared on an average Ubuntu system, but there is one called /usr/share. On my system, most of the folders in /usr/share have permission 755 but individual files have permission 644, 755 or something else. Even if you could boot from a live image, it would still be a lot of work to restore permissions to what they should be. Reinstalling in place is probably much faster. Your error, however, seems to be on the BIOS level and not to do with file system permissions.

Okay, I have modified shared with share, but by reinstalling may be chances of my data loss.

Data should go in /home and is easily backed up and restored. For more elaborate backup strategies, see elsewhere on this site.

If you only modified the permissions of /usr/share i.e. did not apply the change recursively then it should be straightforward to correct from a live boot (or from a recovery shell, if you can obtain one).

@steeldriver, to correct from a live boot, Do I need to install Ubuntu again, or may I correct without installation? Means is there any more description to change permission again back to the original?

@NayanTandel it really depends exactly what you did - if you only changed the permissions on the /usr/share directory itself, then it should be sufficient to restore them to their proper values e.g. sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/
